SequelizeCLI: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')
I'm trying to build a simple next.js app using Sequelize CLI.  However, there are issues with querying the database (migrations are run and all so DB connection is good).
For instance:

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
const { Team } = require('@/models')

export async function GET() {
  const teams = await Team.findAll()
  return NextResponse.json([])
}

As far as I can tell, this should work, but I keep seeing this:
 ⨯ TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')
    at GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/v1/teams/route.js:11:30)

which suggests something isn't right.  I do also see this a lot:
 ⚠ ./models/index.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Everything within @/models is as generated by the CLI.
Edit: To add, some debug information:
const modelsObj = require('@/models')
console.log(Object.keys(modelsObj))

[ 'sequelize', 'Sequelize' ]

